# How do I generate random colour dots on a panel?

Tags: c#

The combobox should generate numbers between 2 and 15 and when user selects a 
number, random coloured dots are drawn randomly on the panel. E.g. user selects 
7, thus, 7 random dots are drawn with random colours.

This is the code I have so far:

```
private void cmbDots_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        randomPaint(Convert.ToInt32(cmbDots.SelectedItem));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}

private void Design_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 2; i <= 15; i++)
    {
        cmbDots.Items.Add(i);
    }
}

private void randomPaint(int numberOfTimes)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
    Color rC;
    SolidBrush b1;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; i++)
    {
        rC = Color.FromArgb(r.Next(255), r.Next(255), r.Next(255));
        b1 = new SolidBrush(rC);
        g.FillEllipse(b1, r.Next(this.Size.Width), r.Next(this.Size.Height), 30, 30);
    }
}
```

Comment: The try and catch (Exception e) there is an error

Comment: Yeah, I'm not seeing the problem either, looks like you have the loop in place that generates a randomly colored 30x30 dot within the constraints of the window...

Comment: I want the dots shown on a panel

Comment: e cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to e, which is already used

Comment: Indeed. Give your exception variable a name other than "e" so it  doesn't clash with the name of your EventArgs parameter. Alternatively, remove the try/catch if you're not going to handle the exception.

Comment: when I choose a number from the combo box nothing is showing on my panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you need to show the dots on a panel, you need to add the panel to the control - if it does not already exist.

```
private void randomPaint(int numberOfTimes)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    Color rC;
    SolidBrush b1;

    Graphics g = pnlDraw.CreateGraphics();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; i++)
    {
        rC = Color.FromArgb(r.Next(255), r.Next(255), r.Next(255));
        b1 = new SolidBrush(rC);
        g.FillEllipse(b1, r.Next(pnlDraw.Size.Width), r.Next(pnlDraw.Size.Height), 30, 30);
    }
}
```

also, change the function for event handling to avoid variable name conflict

```
private void cmbDots_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        randomPaint(Convert.ToInt32(cmbDots.SelectedItem));
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I already added a panel how can I include it in the code? so that it can show on the panel. Its name is pnlDraw.

Comment: Thanks but it is still going outside of the panel

Comment: First, you are not disposing the the Graphics instance and SolidColorBrush that you are creating.  Second, you shouldn't use CreateGraphics for this.  If you use CreateGraphics, the dots will disappear if your window is minimized or if another window passes in front of it.  You should instead use the Paint event of the Panel and the Graphics instance supplied with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use CreateGraphics for this task.  You should use the Paint event of the panel:

```
    int currentDotCount = 0;

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        currentDotCount = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
        panel2.Refresh();
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        randomPaint(currentDotCount, (Panel)sender, e.Graphics);
    }

    private void randomPaint(int numberOfTimes, Panel p, Graphics g)
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; i++)
        {
            using (var b1 = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(r.Next(255), r.Next(255), r.Next(255))))
            {
                g.FillEllipse(b1, r.Next(p.Size.Width), r.Next(p.Size.Height), 30, 30);
            }
        }
    }
```

This will ensure that your graphics are not erased if the form is minimized or if another window passes in front of your panel.